# Synchronize Data Update Using PyODBC and SQL-Alchemy

Tags: python, database, parallel-processing, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a script that is used by several users. In this script, a database table is updated by first deleting and subsequently uploaded.

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('credtials', echo=False)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('credentials')

with pyodbc.connect('...') as cnxn:
    mycursor = cnxn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute('query_delete')
    mycursor.commit()
    mycursor.close()

# Precaluclated dataframe that contains the data (calculation not shown)
df.to_sql(name='db_table', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

The problem is that sometimes it happens that two processes are badly timed. In this case, the sequence of processes is

delete (process 1)
delete (Process 2)
upload (process 1)
upload (process 2)

If this happens, the data are duplicated. Is there a solution to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to tighten up your transaction isolation using code similar to this (untested):

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_uri, isolation_level='SERIALIZABLE')
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text('DELETE FROM db_table WHERE …'))
    df.to_sql(name='db_table', con=conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
print('Update complete.')
```